# program stuck. How do I find the offending code?

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a very big piece of code and whenever it run for 20sec, it will be stuck somewhere and the program freezes. I suspect it stuck in a loop or waiting for some event to happen before it continue.

How do I identify that piece of code? I tried setting breakpoint but it seems too slow. If I set breakpoint at line 1, it will take few hundred iteration before I reach the offending code.

Comment: Pause it when it's stuck?

Comment: try break all / pause when the program is stuck and inspect the threads to see which one is blocking

Comment: We cant guess without some code.

Comment: @Niklas B: Does pausing it help? What do I do after I pause it?

Comment: @user3398315 You inspect the callstacks from the various threads. Open the threads window from `debug -> windows -> threads`. Find a thread that is blocking or stuck in a loop. What type of program is this ? service, forms, WPF, console ? It would be useful if you provide some more context in your question. If it's a gui program you want to inspect the gui thread (main thread) first, as it is most suspected to hanging up the application

Answer (score 3):

Apart from debugging which you have already tried, You can do the following 2 things.

1. Pause the visual studio to see where it is stuck (as mentioned by Niklas B in comments as well)
2. If that isn't helpful you can log the details in some log file that can help you in finding the code that is creating problem.

Though i must say that finding the problem is mostly a tedious job.